# How to delete an item from recyclerview and sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

I try to delete an item from recyclerview and from slqlite data base. 
These are the activities:

1.The database

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public  void deleteTask(long position){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_TASKS, KEY_TASK_ID + "=" + position, null);
    db.close();
}
```

2. The onBindViewHolder from TaskAdapter

TaskAdapter.java

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Task stringTask = tasksList.get(position);
    holder.taskText.setText(stringTask.getTaskName());
    holder.dateText.setText(stringTask.getTaskDate());
    holder.id = stringTask.getID();
    holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){

            tasksList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);

            dth.deleteTask(stringTask.getID());


        }
    });

}
```

This is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.android.todolistapp.DatabaseHandler.deleteTask(long)' on a null object reference
at com.example.android.todolistapp.TaskAdapter$1.onClick(TaskAdapter.java:51)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6935)
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12738)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26211)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: Your dth object seems to be null, can you put the entire class to see the instanciation of it please ?

Answer (score 0):

**dth.deleteTask(stringTask.getID());**
dth is not instantiated. Create object of DatabaseHandler and assign to dth.